# Calculate the blank area of a CANVAS

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, canvas

Help me:

I have a canvas. There are some shapes inside this canvas, these shapes are changing at random over time and they are different types(like: triangle, parallelogram, trapezium, square, circle etc). There are also some blank space/area in that canvas left after these shapes rendered each time.

Now how can I calculate that area of blank space of that canvas after each time those shapes are rendered at random?

Comment: Knowing nothing about your actual design, it's hard to tell. The only way to precisely determine this is to calculate the area of canvas, subtract to that the area of all your shapes (you need to have a reference to those shapes stored somewhere) and add the area of the intersections between the shapes. The imprecise but convenient and design-agnostic way to do it would be to count the blank pixels left on the canvas.

Comment: if the backgound of your canvas is all th same color u can loop through all the pixels and compare the number of backround color pixels to all other colored pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the areas of the shapes from the canvas area.

If the shapes do not overlap this is the requested area.

If the shapes overlap you could calculate the overlaps add these back to the previously found area.

If it is too difficult to calculate the areas and overlaps you could go brute force and render the canvas to a bitmap and count colored pixels.